# Do different app activities share same processes in a task?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new to android. I know we can launch activities belonging to different appps . My confusion is when I launch activity(B1) of different app(B) from my app's(A) activity(A1) a new process is created or B1 also belong to same process. I know they belong to same task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default each app runs in it's own process. So unless one of the apps is doing something special or using a shared user ID, they will run in different processes.

Comment: So in that case if there are n instances of activity A1 of app A created by different app will belong to app A process ?? if yes will they be sharing single UI thread for all activity

Comment: The number of instances depends on intent flags, etc. but generally you get N instances if you call `startActivity()` N times. There is only one UI thread for the whole system. Are you trying to do something specific or just looking for information?

Answer (score 0):

Android assigns a unique sand box for each application, this is enforced by the kernel.  The underlying communication between applications go through the OS bus.

So the answer is no, they don't belong to the same process.

Comment: So if we launch 5 instances of an application will each one of those applications have the same Process Id?